# The controllability of a system whose adjacency matrix has a combination of negative and positive eigenvalues

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I'm currently working on a multidisciplinary research project about the structural controllability of brain networks. Specifically, I have constructed the adjacency matrix of brain networks and studied their controllability given a different input matrix $B$. However, I've received a comment about my work that I'm not sure how to approach.

The question is: "Is the $A$ matrix that is estimated stable, i.e., are the real parts of all the eigenvalues negative? If not, then the model in equation 1 is describing the structural brain as an unstable dynamic system."

I've considered the dynamics in brain networks by linear models, and equation 1 in the comment points out $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$. My constructed adjacency matrices are zero-one $90 \times 90$ and symmetric. Therefore, as far as I know, their eigenvalues are real. But, when I calculated the eigenvalues, I found that it has a combination of negative and positive values, and the number of positive values is almost thirty out of ninety.

I would like to know if my idea is appropriate for this situation. From my understanding, if $\dot{x} = Ax$ for a system, and all the eigenvalues of $A$ are negative, then the system is considered stable. Conversely, if all the eigenvalues are positive, then the system is considered unstable. However, when we encounter a system with some positive eigenvalues in controllability, we can drive the system into stability by properly selecting the inputs $Bu$, $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$.

I would appreciate any help in dealing with this comment regarding my work.

Comment: I agree with the reviewer's comment: if matrix $A$ has positive eigenvalues, the corresponding eigenmodes will then grow exponentially in time (if $u(t)=0$). In general that kind of instability is a serious concern which must be avoided. Or maybe instability is not an issue with the application you have in mind, in which case you should explain why in detail.

Comment: @A.Thibault, thank you for clarification. I've been learning about control theory and linear dynamics, so please correct me if I am wrong. From what I understand, in the equation $\dot{x} = Ax$, the system is considered stable if all eigenvalues of A are negative, and unstable if all are positive. However, in controllability, if some positive eigenvalues exist in $A$, we can drive the system into stability by adding $Bu$, and proper inputs can address existing instability. As you mentioned, if $u(t) = 0$, the system will grow exponentially. But what happens if $u(t)$ does not equal zero?

Comment: Are you sure that your model is correct? Namely, normally an adjacency matrix only indicates whether two points (in this case two neurons I assume) are connected, but not what kind of interaction they have.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, based on structural connections between neurons, I constructed an adjacency matrix A, regardless of interaction type. Thus, if there is a connection between nodes $i$ and $j$, then $A_{i, j} = 1$, otherwise is zero.

Comment: @samie What KwinvanderVeen said is correct. The adjacency matrix only describes the network topology, that is, what what neuron interact with one given neuron. This does not say anything on how those neurons interact with that neuron (i.e. the dynamics). In fact, it is also very unclear what your state is here? What is $x$ exactly? What is $u$?

Comment: @KBS, Thank you for sharing your feedback. I will conduct further research on the model. However, I have a question. Assuming the model is correct, can we control a system with a combination of positive and negative eigenvalues in the adjacency matrix by using appropriate inputs $Bu(t)$?

Comment: @samie Yes, a system can be controllable even if it has both positive and negative eigenvalues. Just pick $\dot{x}=x+u$. which is unstable but controllable. But the problem here is that your overall set-up seems to be incorrect and would need to be fixed before continuing any further. I would also encourage you to look at structural controllability.

Comment: @KBS, Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I am currently researching the structural controllability of brain networks and I added it to the question. Constructing an accurate weighted adjacency matrix can be challenging, and this is one of the reasons why I am focusing on the structural controllability of these networks. Does it impact the confusion that has been raised about my setup?

Comment: I recommend you read about linear controllability in the book "Linear Matrix Theory" by William Rugh.

Comment: @samie In that case, I would recommend you to look at the graph conditions for structural controllability. This has been extensively studied in control and network science.